# have an issue with Dataframe in python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have issues with dataframe, please i need help

[image: Picture 1 and code]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# example - Revenue of companies

revenue_df = pd.read_clipboard()
print revenue_df
```

[image: Error Message and picture 2]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Techie-Jife/PycharmProjects/Data Science/DataFrame.py", line 6, in <module>
    revenue_df = pd.read_clipboard()
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboards.py", line 85, in read_clipboard
    return read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=sep, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1139, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2415, in read
    alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 3066, in _rows_to_cols
    self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)
  File "C:\Users\Techie-Jife\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2835, in _alert_malformed
    raise ParserError(msg)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: 3 is the data i got from wikipedia]

Comment: Please also post the contents of your clipboard. Also don't use clipboard, but actually define the table somewhere.

Comment: Agreed. You aren't really going to know what the issue is unless you look at the contents of your clipboard. This seems like a confusing way to try and process your data.

Comment: it's from a data science course i puchased on Udemy, i'm still trying to rap mmy head around this Dataframe

Answer (score 0):

edited this by your latest error

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d = '''50   Lukoil  Oil and gas $119,145    Increase $9,863 102,500 Russia Russia   [54]
49  Fannie Mae  Financials  $120,101    Increase $15,959    7,400   United States United States [53]
48  General Electric    Conglomerate    $120,268    Decrease -$22,355   283,000 United States United States [52]
47  Kroger  Retail  $121,162    Increase $3,110 453,000 United States United States [51]'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, header=None, lineterminator="\n")

df
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   50  Lukoil  Oil and gas $119,145    Increase $9,863 102,500 Russia Russia   [54]
1   49  Fannie Mae  Financials  $120,101    Increase $15,959    7,400   United States United States [53]
2   48  General Electric    Conglomerate    $120,268    Decrease -$22,355   283,000 United States United States [52]
3   47  Kroger  Retail  $121,162    Increase $3,110 453,000 United States United States [51]
```

[image]

Comment: , line 9, in <module>
    revenue_df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+')
NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Comment: paste your copied data into d and remember to use triple qoutes (').

Comment: I'm currently using Python 2 to learn but this codes you dropped do not still work, that's the error code above

Comment: data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 955, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2172, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5

Comment: I did what you asked me to do, this is the error code it's showing me

Comment: I did what you asked me to do, this is the error code it's showing me

Comment: try not to copy header that the things causing the errors

Comment: No, I'm still battling with it, i think a package is missing in my pycham or python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Edit1: you dont face a problem if you dont select the header to clipboard.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# example - Revenue of companies

revenue_df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t', header=None)
print (revenue_df)
```

Comment: data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 955, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2172, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 5, saw 8

Comment: @eddywickliffe you are selecting the header of the table as well. Don't select it.
I mean don't select Rank, Name, ... . Start From 1 in the second line

Comment: Later add then separately to your df. `revenue_df.columns=['Rank','Name',..]`

Comment: the copied data needs to convert into bytes using StringIO to transform into dataframe, the error code return read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=sep, **kwargs) pasted with question says it clearly